Symfony/JMoseCommandScheduler: override timezone
I am using Symfony 4 with JMoseCommandScheduler, it works fine.
However, I would like to make the list of cron commands bound to a specific timezone.
Editing the bundle source code, it can be achieve in JMose\CommandSchedulerBundle\Command\ExecuteCommand::execute()
<?php

    namespace JMose\CommandSchedulerBundle\Command;
...
    class ExecuteCommand extends Command
    {
    ...
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
        ...
                $cron = CronExpression::factory($command->getCronExpression());
                $nextRunDate = $cron->getNextRunDate($command->getLastExecution());
        ...
        }
    }

Updating line 128 to compare with cron timezone will do the trick:
$nextRunDate = $cron->getNextRunDate($command->getLastExecution(), 0, false, 'Europe/Paris');

(I don't want to change php script in UTC timezone).
Now I am trying to achieve the same result without tweaking bundle source code.
Would you know how it can be done?
